# Javascript redirect to URL controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How do I redirect to controller in .net core 3.1 MVC. I need to replace alert(data) with however the proper way is to redirect such as: Url.RouteUrl("Companies\Detail1?id = data"

```
     function commandClick(args) {
                                // here we are making an ajax call to server
                                if (args.commandColumn.buttonOption.id === "jumpPlan") {
                                    var ajax = new ej.base.Ajax({
                                        url: "/Companies/Jump2Plan",
                                        type: "POST",
                                        contentType: "application/json",
                                        data: JSON.stringify({ value: args.rowData })
                                    });
                                    ajax.send();

                                    ajax.onSuccess = function (data) {
                                        //    // on the success event we are showing the data returned from server
                                        alert(data);
                                    };
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

window.location.replace("/Companies/Detail1?id=data");